# HttpErrors configuration working on Windows 10 but not on Server 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-7.5, episerver

I have an EPiServer web application that I am running which has a CMS controlled 404 page. I have custom errors off and the following in the web.config for httpErrors

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/404/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/500.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

There is a flag in the CMS which allows the /404/ CMS error page to send a 404 status code using

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

This is all working perfectly well and dancy on my local Windows 10 instance, however when I deploy it to a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance and testing going to a not known URL it takes minutes for the page to load as I think it's getting in some sort of loop.

Any ideas as to the difference, I know there's some settings around the applicationHosts for SkippingIIs errors, does anyone know how to get it to work?

Comment: I think you're referring to `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true`, which you should add to your 404 controller.

You also need to configure `system.web/customErrors`, otherwise you're only catching 404's from IIS, not from your code as well.

Comment: Another tip is to redirect errors to an aspx instead of a static html page. Otherwise you're not able to return a 500 error code to the client. You don't need a code-behind for the page, just put `<% Response.StatusCode = 500 %>` somewhere on the page.

Comment: No I'm aware of TrySkipIisCustomErrors and have tried adding that but it makes no difference to my issue. And I'm not so bothered about the 500 code, just the 404 at this point.

Comment: How does your route for 404, controller and view look like?

Comment: I'm sure this is configuration, I've tested this on multiple windows10, windows 2012 R2 instances and it works on the windows10 boxes, I've been comparing the module configuration in the applicationHosts to see what the differences are but trying to fix with no luck. The routing FYI is standard PageData -> Controller EPiServer routing from the content page. But I know this is working perfectly.

Comment: So the 404 is a page in Episerver? Does it have the URL /404/? Can you access it directly? Make sure it´s accessible without the language segment, i.e. /en/404/.